# How do you use the Svelte-i18n CLI?

Tags: internationalization, svelte

There's a CLI documented in the Svelte-i18n package, and it seems like it could be a useful tool, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use it. Does anyone have a clue for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a useful tool. By following the steps, you can use them.

Install Svelte-i18n package.

```
npm install --save-dev svelte-i18n
```

Add this script in package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
  "extract-messages": "svelte-i18n extract src/**/*.svelte --output-dir locales"
}
```

Add this function in svelte components.

```
<script>
  import { t } from 'svelte-i18n';
</script>

<p>{$t('hello')}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. that's what I was missing. I thought that I could call svelte-i18n directly in the terminal. I lacked a svelte.config.sys file as well, but that was easily cured.